# For Postgres, how would I define a custom function to generate primary keys?

Tags: postgresql, primary-key, functions

In postgres, primary keys are typically generated using a [SEQUENCE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-createsequence.html). I am hoping to generate a unique random 12 character string for use as a primary key.
How would I do this in Postgres?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Maybe the UUID type is what you need? At any rate, you should be able to specify your own function to be called for default values for a column.

Comment: @Colin'tHart thank you - I had not discovered the UUID datatype and it serves my purposes exactly, though the generated strings are longer than I need. 
Defining a function for a default value seems like a very good candidate solution as well. If you want to make your comment an answer I'd be happy to accept it.

Comment: Create a function that does what you want, then use `create table foo (some_column varchar default my_function());`

Comment: @Ivar You want a long value, like a uuid, if relying on randomness. Otherwise you're going to get collisions between generated keys in concurrent sessions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turning the comments into an Answer so we can close this Question.

## 12-chars not random enough

A 12-character random string may be a poor choice for a [surrogate key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key). Your generated values might have a significant chance of colliding, especially depending on your particular implementation for generating such values.

No need to invent such an identifier, as the industry has defined one already: UUID.

## UUID

A better route would be using a standard [Universally Unique Identifier (UUID)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UUID). A UUID is a 128-bit value. Though usually displayed as a string of thirty-two hexadecimal characters plus four hyphens (36 chars total), Postgres knows how to compactly store a UUID natively as 128-bit. Postgres also supports indexing a UUID column, so the UUID type serves well as a [primary key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_key#Defining_primary_keys_in_SQL).

The [original version of UUIDs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Version_1_.28date-time_and_MAC_address.29) are unique in space and time by combining the generating computer’s [MAC address](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=13&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwio3JrSyunUAhXHq1QKHemwCTkQFgheMAw&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FMAC_address&usg=AFQjCNGRYb-_Exc0MyLimHmyvSI618d3lw), the current moment, plus a small random number. You may choose alternative versions if security or privacy concerns require that you not encode the place (MAC address) or the time (current moment).

One advantage of UUIDs is that they may be generated either on the server-side and/or the client-side (within your app).

An advantage of using standard UUIDs instead of roll-your-own values is that all mainstream operating systems and development platforms already have high-quality implementations for generating quality UUIDs. No need to implement and document your roll-your-own algorithm.

Postgres has built-in support for *storing* UUID values. To *generate* UUID values, you need a plug-in, an “extension”.  The [*uuid-ossp*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/uuid-ossp.html) extension is usually bundled with a distribution of Postgres, but you may need to activate it.

For more info, see the Question, [*Generating a UUID in Postgres for Insert statement?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12505158/642706).